Is there a Python-pptx function to update Excel embedded links?
I have a question about the Python-pptx library.
I have a PowerPoint presentation with Excel links and when I refresh the Excel file base, I then open the PowerPoint presentation and refresh the links to get new data.
My question is this

Can Presentation Links be Updated using this library?
Can the update be done with the entire presentation? Ó Does the Link have to be updated for each shape within each Slide?

Thanks
Presentation and Excel Automation in conjunction with Python

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
